# Number of ways of seating around a rectangular table

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can 14 people be seated around a rectangular table having 5 seats along the longer side and 2 seats along the shorter side?

I tried to solve this and thought of it as a circular table with 14 positions.
And my answer was $\frac{13!}{2}$. But it came wrong.

Where I went wrong and how should I steer in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2):

The first person has $7$ options (he is the one who determines the orientation/ break symmetry).

After that, the other can choose their seat.

Hence in total, there are $7 \cdot 13!$ ways.